# Python-like Dictionary in R where keys are int?

Tags: python, r

I know that R can simulate python like dictionaries when the keys are strings:

```
    dictionary1 = c('a'=1, 'b'=2, 'c'=3)
```

However, how can I emulate this when the keys are int? i.e. in python it's

```
    pydict1 = {1:5, 2:6, 3:4}
```

Comment: You can use backticks `c(\`1\` = 1)` or quotes `c("1" = 1)` for setting non-standard names.

Comment: Why not do something like `dict1 = c("1"=5, "2"=6, "3" = 4)` and so on. Then use `strtoi`, if necessary

Comment: You could use the sparseVector function from the Matrix package.